# finding which radio button was selected without using a *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have tried this many different ways:

```
 <input type="radio" name="group" id="ssnRadio" [checked]="ssn" [(ngModel)]="ssnSelected">
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="group" [checked]="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastNameSelected" >
```

There are more radio buttons but they are step up like the above. They are all separate thus not in a `*ngFor`

in the component I have the following:

```
  ssnSelected: boolean;
    userIdSelected: boolean;
    lastNameSelected: boolean;
    officeSelected: boolean;
    roleSelected: boolean;

    selectedRow: number;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.ssnSelected=false;
        this.userIdSelected=false;
        this.lastNameSelected=false;
        this.officeSelected=false;
        this.roleSelected=false;
    }
```

And the button has this method in it when it:

```
 search() {

        if (this.ssnSelected==true) {
            console.log( this.ssn);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserBySSN(this.ssn);
        }
        if (this.userIdSelected == true) {
            console.log(this.userId);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserById(this.userId);
        }
```

So I need to find what radio button was selected so I can call the correct service and pass in a value that is using two way binding to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need checkbox if it is just true and false situation

and you may use below,

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="ssnSelected" > SSN Selected
```

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXJ0xdem0QFvZ51c334m?p=preview)!!

**Update:**

based upon comment it seems you need to be selecting just one from a radio button group, You can try below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <label><input type="radio"  name="group" value="ssn" [(ngModel)]="groupVal" > SSN</label>
  <label><input type="radio"  name="group" value="lastname" [(ngModel)]="groupVal" > Last name</label>
  <label><input type="radio"  name="group" value="role" [(ngModel)]="groupVal" > SSN Role</label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button (click)="search()" >Search</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  groupVal = "ssn";
  name = 'Angular'; 

  search(){
   switch(this.groupVal){
     case "ssn":
        console.log("ssn selected");
        break;
     case "lastname":
        console.log("lastname selected");
        break;
     case "role":
        console.log("role selected");
        break;
      default:
        break;
   }
  }
}
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXJ0xdem0QFvZ51c334m?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I had that BUT I need it to have radio button functionality. They can only select one checkbox and when they select another checkbox the prior one is uncheck. Hence radio button functionality.

Comment: @Drew1208: updated answer based on your comment, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the form changes or individual input changes.

```
<input type="radio" 
    name="group" 
    id="ssnRadio" 
    [checked]="ssn" 
    [(ngModel)]="ssnSelected" 
    (change)="doSomething($event)">
```

Comment: This does appear to be the right route but can you elaborate?